# Getting /feed/ behind post urls in Google Webmaster Tools; crawler errors?

Tags: feed

Currently I have a wordpress site submitted in Google Webmaster Tools. But at the Crawler Errors page, I see a lot of : site.nl/post/feed. Does anyone know how these get there and how to get rid of em?

Answer (score 1):

Those are ['pretty permalink'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) style Feed URLs. Google doesn't guess at URLs, so your site must be printing them somewhere. Or, your site used to print them and you've since disabled your feeds or broken them somehow. Google would then have those URLs in its database.

You have to make sure your site isn't mistakenly printing bad URLs, then, if your site is no longer printing the bad URLs, they will drop out of Google's database eventually. You can set them to 'fixed' in webmaster tools but they will show up if Google finds the link again.

Comment: s_ha_dum thanks for your reply. Is there any way to make sure my site isn't mistakenly printing bad urls?

Comment: Webmaster Tools will tell you where Google found the links. Click on a 404 link (down in the table under the graph), then click on "Linked From". If the link is coming from you site follow it and you can should see where the problem is, at least.

Comment: s_ha_dum, I just noticed where the links come from, but to be honest I don't know how to edit them, as they are generated by the <?php wp_head(); ?>

This is what it generates:
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Sitename &raquo; My Post Comments feed" href="http://www.mysite.com/my-post/feed" />

Comment: Those are comment feeds and they look correct. Have you changed permalinks? Something like that?